# Php Stream image from private to public folder

Tags: php

I have an JPG image stored in

`/app/storage/foobar.jpg`

And I wanna show this in:
`/public/foobar.php`

The JPG isn't stored in public repository, so I have to do something different then `<img src="/images/foobar.jpg">`.

What I have:`

```
$path = '/app/storage/foobar.jpg'; // or something equal, lets say this returns the correct JPG
$_mime = 'image/jpeg';
        $headers = [
            'Content-Type'              => $_mime,
            'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => 'binary',
            'Content-Disposition'       => 'inline; filename="foobar"',
            'Expires'                   => 0,
            'Cache-Control'             => 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0',
            'Pragma'                    => 'public',
            'Content-Length'            => filesize($path),
        ];
```

And then? Now i have the headers

Comment: You can set up the src to be a php file that only returns the image.  However, now all of your img src's are going to go to a file, so they won't get cached for SEO.  Does that matter to you?

Comment: why don't you pick one of the many working examples first we have on site? Many of the then detailed questions are also already part of the existing Q&A material we have on site already.